# About the signature: int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE p1, HINSTANCE p2, LPSTR p3, int p4)

Tags: c, winapi

Why can `WinMain` have two return types?

If I remove it,will report this warning:

```
warning C4007: 'WinMain' : must be '__stdcall'
```

Or I'm reading int `WINAPI` wrongly?

**UPDATE**

I tried these two variants which are said to be the same as `WINAPI`,none work:

```
int __declspec WinMain

int __declspec(stdcall) WinMain
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WINAPI` isn't a return type it's a macro expanding to an implementation specific decoration or attribute for the function. In this instance it specifies the calling convention and is equivalent to `__stdcall` .

Grammatically, WINAPI is roughly (but not exactly) equivalent to a storage class specifier like `static`.

Comment: But what does `__declspec(stdcall)` mean then? The regular form should be: `[return type] function_name(parameters)`,right?

Comment: @user198729: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention . And yes, normally it should just be `returnType func(parameters)`, but `__declspec` is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: @user198729: That's the simplest form of function declaration. The function could also be declared `static` or `inline` which affects the meaning of the function declaration but not the return type. `WINAPI` is a windows specific extension that specifies the calling convention but doesn't otherwise change the meaning of the function declaration.

Comment: @jamesdlin , do you mean that calling convention only exists for windows?

Comment: My fault, It's `__stdcall`, not __declspec(stdcall); it's meaning is what I originally stated, though.

Comment: All platforms have a calling convention. Some have ways of choosing a specific calling convention (like windows); others only support a single calling convention so it's never mentioned or specified in code.

Answer (score 2):

`WINAPI` is not a second return value, but a `#define` for [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28VS.71%29.aspx).

__stdcall is a calling convention, that handles amongst others how the parameters are given to the function.

Comment: So `__stdcall` is the same as `__declspec(stdcall)` mentioned by @Charles Bailey,right?

Comment: I think it is, though I only know it in the `__stdcall` form, that is used in <WinDef.h>

Comment: Does this kinda stuff only exists in windows?

Comment: `WINAPI` and `__stdcall` are Microsoft specific but other platforms can and do have their own extensions for using something other than the standard calling convention.